# Why does retrieving an invalid endpoint in .NET 6 through the HttpContext for a GET and a POST return different result?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-6.0

I have a .NET 6 middleware that checks a few things and in it I am trying to validate whether the request provided has a proper route or not.

I have the following in my middleware

```
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
{
     // This returns null if it's a GET to an invalid route. 
     // But it returns method not supported if it's a POST/PUT
     var endpoint = context.Features.Get<IEndpointFeature>()?.Endpoint;
}
```

Why is .NET 6 returning two different values for this and is there a better way to identify early on in a middleware that a request does not have the correct route?

Comment: `is there a better way to identify early on in a middleware that a request does not have the correct route`You want to check request method type before getting endpoint?

Comment: I thing there's another Middleware (e.g. StaticFileMiddleware) catching this before your Middleware. Read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#middleware-order) about Middleware ordering

Answer (score 2):

From source code of [EndpointMiddleware.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Http/Routing/src/EndpointMiddleware.cs), the middleware from app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => [...]);

To get an endpoint object in a middleware you have to use this method :

```
public Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
{
    var endpoint = httpContext.GetEndpoint();
    [...]
}
```

The endpoint variable will be null if the requested route doesn't match any known routes.

In startup.cs you have to add your middleware just after app.UseRouting() which is responsible of making the match.